# Connect custom iOS app to Apple TV app

Tags: ios, apple-tv

If I created my own iOS app, would I be able to connect to my own Apple TV app via Bluetooth or WiFi or do I have to go through the slow API server method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use your iOS app as a remote controller for Apple TV (check https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cidertv-free-best-remote-app/id1017677047?mt=8) to directly communicate via bluetooth. There's no equivalent of `WatchConnectivity` to directly communicate your iOS app with tvOS app, like you would do with watchOS. Of course you can use LAN (probably Bonjour, etc) to communicate, but it still requires a WIFI router, etc to connect 2 devices in one network. And it won't be an easy task. But I think there are some games that work on LAN, so it's possible. The easiest way will be probably via server.

Comment: Thanks. The idea would be there are several people with iPhones and their iPhones show a poker hand. And on the TV is a poker table. Everyone would be in the same room, so nothing remote. Another example would be a trivia question on the screen and everyone's iPhone being a buzzer to buzz in.

Comment: Then this should be interesting for you: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/ChoosingTheRightNetworkingAPI/ChoosingTheRightNetworkingAPI.html
And this one: https://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1

Comment: GameKit's connectivity code was replaced witch MultipeerConnectivity so this might be useful: https://developer.apple.com/reference/multipeerconnectivity#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013328-CH1-SW1